Dynamically store global variables in Visual Studio Code for running http file
I want to utilize the http files in my project similar to Swagger or Postman for storing auth headers such as csrf and bearer token.
I couldn't find a way to store tokens dynamically, so I created this flow:

get the csrf token requst - copy the token
paste the csrf token in login request as variable and make login request - res is authtoken
for each new request i need to  paste the csrf and auth token

The expected flow:

get csrf token and store the res.token inside global env such as task.json
make login req by using the csrf from task.json and store the login res.token there
all other req will consume variables from there

I try to create a task.json file to manage it but I can't find how to do that.
Example of my current flow:
POST {{baseUrl}}/init/get
Content-Type: application/json
}

# want find a way to store the res which is {csrf:someJWTtoken}

The login :
POST http://localhost:8000/users/login
Content-Type:application/json
Csrftoken:{{csrf => want consume it from prev req automatically}}

{"email":"foo@boomail.com","password":"foo&boo"}

#store the res cookie in the global task.json

